# Why my color of directories in putty is same as other color for linux

Tags: windows-7, centos, putty

I am using putty to link to centos.

however my directories all are showing in one single color.

But in other terminal to ubuntu it shows directories as blue color.

how can i fix that

Comment: What version CentOS? Also, take a look here: http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/change-centos-ssh-shell-color/

Comment: centos6.3 , with byobu and putty

Comment: I tried that with root but it chaged the color of dir with root only. When i go back to user again color go back to normal. i think my file gets overwritten every time

Comment: @user1721949: what shell do you use for root login and for user login?

Comment: i i use same putty termianl and then sudo to root

Comment: Take a look at the .bashrc and .bash_profile files for root. Figure out what lines in those files make it work for root, and then copy them into your own environment scripts. Don't just copy the whole file  though... that could be very bad!

Answer (score 0):

Put this entry in .bashrc

```
LS_COLORS='di=0;35'; export LS_COLORS
```

And put this entry in .bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

Comment: i tried it but color didn't chnaged